# Too many arguments in call to "github.com/jackc/pgx".Connect

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

I am trying to open a connection to a postgres database using pgx and I am getting the following error:

```
./dbservice.go:12:26: too many arguments in call to "github.com/jackc/pgx".Connect
        have (context.Context, string)
        want ("github.com/jackc/pgx".ConnConfig)
./dbservice.go:13:18: too many arguments in call to conn.Close
        have (context.Context)
        want ()
./dbservice.go:21:44: cannot use context.Background() (type context.Context) as type string in argument to conn.Query
```

I am not sure what the error is asking me to do here. `pgx.Connect` works when I call it from the main file but here it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
func initNodes(nodes *[]Node, searchNodes *[]SearchNode, storageNodes *[]StorageNode) error {
    conn, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), DATABATE_URL)
    defer conn.Close(context.Background())

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Connection failed: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(-1)
    }
...

func main() {
    a:= Arbiter{}
    a.init()
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How is pgx imported in main? How is it imported here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you are importing the `v3` `pgx` API in `dbservice.go`, but the `v4` API in your “main file”. The [`Connect`](https://beta.pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4@v4.13.0#Connect) function in `github.com/jackc/pgx/v4` accepts the two arguments you're passing. The [`Connect`](https://beta.pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx@v3.6.2+incompatible#Connect) function in `v3` accepts a `pkg.ConnConfig` instead.

So, check your `import` statements in `dbservice.go`: if you intend to be using the `v4` API, import it as `"github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"`.